# Display data from JSON to Text view using ng-repeat and ng-model data conflict

Tags: html, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have an API code that can generate this particular result:

```
[
  {
    "devid": "3",
    "name": "abacus",
    "type": "math device",

  },
  {
    "devid": "4",
    "name": "beaker",
    "type": "science device",
  }
]
```

Now, I can call this json response in my html file already using an array that i put inside my controller. This is my controller code:

```
labserviceService.lab1(id)
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.device = data.data;
                $scope.deviceID = data.data[0].devid;
                $scope.devicename = data.data[0].name;
                $scope.devicetype = data.data[0].type;

            });
```

How can I display the data in my div using ng-repeat and ng -model? This is my div section

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in device">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            ID:
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="deviceID">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            Name:
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="devicename">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            Type:
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="devicetype">
        </div>
            <br><br>
</div>
```

I tried this code but the the value that is only displayed and repeated is the first set, the second one isn't displayed at all. How can I display all the data in the json?Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Use an array to get all data from your response, for example:

```
$scope.device= [];

labserviceService.lab1(id)
                .then(function(data){
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                       var myData= {
                            deviceID: data.data[i].devid,
                            devicename: data.data[i].name,                                
                            devicetype: data.data[i].type
                       }
                       $scope.device.push(myData);
                    }        
                });
```

Then add the ng-repeat:

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in device"> <!-- This is $scope.device -->
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            ID: item.deviceID
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="item.deviceID">
        </div>
         <!-- and so on... item.devicename item.devicetype--> 
</div>
```

I hope help you. I'm not sure what do you want to do later...